# Read elements from a file and store them in ArrayList as Objects

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have a file contains (string, int, floating, char)

12

1.8

a

John

23.5

I want to read them an store them in an ArrayList. My ArrayList type is object. But, still I get exceptions when I run it.

```
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{


    try{
            FileReader a=new FileReader("src/SET_A.txt");
            Scanner b=new Scanner(a);
            ArrayList<Object> c=new ArrayList<Object>();
            while(b.hasNextLine())
                {
                    Object d=b.nextInt();
                    c.add(d);
                 }
            System.out.println("The content of arraylist is: " + a);
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

Comment: What are your exceptions?  Or are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Only one of the lines is an int - maybe next() would be a better method

Comment: With no info about what exception you're getting, we can only guess what's wrong. My guess is that there is no file at `"src/SET_A.txt"` relative to where you are executing this code.

Comment: calling nextInt on a scanner when checking for nextLine is a recipe for disaster, especially when the file contains int Strings, double Strings, and well, String Strings.  Why not check for hasNextLine() and get nextLine()?

Answer (score 0):

Are you displaying the File or the Contents of ArrayList? You should be displaying C and not A. If not, please let us know what is the Exception.